# How to merge multiple reports in print

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex, apex, apex-code

I need to create a print button that prints many reports and not one report.

Image

[image: 1]

I create a print button but print one report by query link, but I need to print 2 or 3 reports in one button.

Answer (score 0):

> print one report by **query link**

In that case, try to

- let button submit the page (i.e. no link on button at all)
- create one branch per report you'd like to print
- as branch lets you define link and pass parameters to it, do it
- set branch's Server side condition - "When button pressed" - and set it to the submit button